# ASP.NET MVC - Sorting forum threads depending on last post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am writing simple forum in ASP.NET MVC.

In category view I want to show the newest threads.

My code with sorting by thread add date:

```
model.ForumThreads = db.ForumThreads
   .Where(t => t.ForumThreadCategoryId == id)
   .OrderByDescending(t => t.AddDate)
   .ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

ForumPost model has foreign key to ForumThread model.

The problem is:
How to sort threads by last post, but if there is no posts then sort by thread add date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ternary `if` operator (if`?`then`:`else):

```
model.ForumThreads = db.ForumThreads
   .Where(t => t.ForumThreadCategoryId == id)
   .OrderByDescending(t => t.ForumPosts.Any() //if
                         ? t.ForumPosts.Max(x=>x.AddDate) //then by post add date
                         : t.AddDate) //else like you already do
   .ToPagedList(page, 10);
```